# "Where my sister was" vs. "Where was my sister"

Tags: reported-speech, direct-speech

> He asked me: Where my sister was.

or

> He asked me: Where was my sister.

Are both correct? If one of them is not correct, what is the reason for that?

Comment: Is what he asked you a direct quote (the kind you can put inside of quotation marks), or is it reported speech (the kind you talk about, but don't put in quotation marks)?  The correct answer to your question depends on this subtlety.

Comment: And note that the colon is **a)** unnecessary with a direct quote--basically a rhetorical 'stage direction'--and **b)** unusual almost to the point of ungrammaticality with a 'nominal' relative clause. Moreover **c)**, you would not start the indirect version of the question with a capital letter.